# Removing n times duplicated data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

since i have the following data in elastic search (2.x)

All the json messages are stored under the same index named "test"

```
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "2", "severity": "critical"}
{"message_id": "2", "severity": "critical"}
{"message_id": "2", "severity": "critical"}
{"message_id": "2", "severity": "critical"}
```

Each json has been duplicated 4 times. Is there any way i can run a delete query in elastic serch and preserve only

```
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "2", "severity": "critical"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that duplicated messages are really stored? Keep in mind, that those 4 JSONs

```
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
```

is the same as:

```
{"message_id": "1", "severity": "info"}
```

Applying the same JSON (PUT), will result in replacing a elastic-search document with renewed one.

Comment: Yes i am sure that there are 4 entries. Everytime when it got inserted into elastic search the new _id was generated. i.e . all 4 records has different _id value. i just want to eliminate those and get only one row. How can i do it

Comment: When a new id is generated, it logically means you don't put it. Can you please retrieve a mapping of your index (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Need to first find all duplicates using aggregation:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/type1/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "field": "message_id",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Step 2: After you get the list of the duplicates, run a loop to call DELETE on all those document with the '_id' returned in step 1.